# Explaining Function behavior

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm going through some Kotlin tutorials and i came across a function behavior that i can't explain.

When i define a function without specifying its return type in the function signature the code runs smoothly. When i do, it gives an error saying "A return expression required in a function with a block body".

Please have a look at the images i'm attaching.

Hope my question is clear.

This is the code with the error:
[image]

This is the code without error when i add the return type of the function in the function signature:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
fun isOpen(hour: Int): Boolean {}
```

The "`: Boolean`" part means that the function *must* return a `Boolean` (true or false) value or it is not valid and the program will not compile.

If you write `return status` at the end of the function, the function will then return the value of the `status` variable to the caller. It will then also be a valid function and your program should compile.